# Drupal: how to pass variable from node to block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-7

I'd like to do in

1. do some processing of node fields in `node.tpl.php`
2. save it to a variable
3. and display in a block that is loaded after the node (on the same page).

**How to pass a variable from a node to a block?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're running Drupal 7, you have access to the new [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) function, from either a custom module or theme. By implementing this, you can easily move parts of the main content area (eg, the node), into any number of different blocks. You'll want to use the [show()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/show/7), [hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/hide/7) and [render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) functions to properly hide content.

Alternatively, using show() and hide() from within your node.tpl.php template should properly hide the elements, and then you could grab the node object from your block using the [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function.

There is normally a video available on hook_page_alter() [here](http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/page-render-drill-down-drupal-7), but the site is down at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, @jhedstrom, hook_page_alter() seems perfect for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

> do some processing of node fields in
>   `node.tpl.php`

A purist would say that you shouldn't be doing it there. [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) can be used for processing of fields.

Then you can just use [menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) in your block to get the `$node` object and access any values you have added to it.